# pyspark insert appear java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out;'I have been running steadily for a month, but suddenly it's like this

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tt_idata_can.py", line 165, in <module>
    mydf.write.insertInto("{}.tg_event_delta".format(db), overwrite=True)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.5-1.cdh7.1.5.p68.27027502/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 750, in insertInto
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.5-1.cdh7.1.5.p68.27027502/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.5-1.cdh7.1.5.p68.27027502/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'shaded.hwc.org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out;'
```

After running again, I found it strange to still be like this

Comment: I believe it is expected if you are running a job for long time.. some times cluster may not be respond well hence you may have to restart system.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, the total task duration exceeded 2 hours, and this insert operation took 50 minutes to execute. This is an error reported by the insert operation. Could it be because I have written too many partitions? Because I delete them every time I use them, my logic below is to retrieve the amount of data saved. Could it be caused by my select count (1) from tg_evend_delta operation? It is difficult to troubleshoot

Comment: please share your code without code it is difficult to suggest for any one.

Comment: It needs some more of problem explanation